# Laravel: Recursive Validation Per Rule

Tags: php, laravel, validation, recursion, laravel-5

I'm working on an admin panel where an administrator can setup validation custom validation rules for membership applications. I understand need to setup a $attribute => $rules pair in the database.

However, there is a requested feature I am not quite sure how to implement. The administrator wants each $key => $rule pair to recursively and optionally have children $key => $rule pairs that would be executed if the parent failed. So in the end, each rule could have 0 to many children rules that would all need to pass to make the parent rule pass.

Example:

```
// Original validation (Assume age = 16, time_at_job = 18 and monthly_income = 3000)
[
    'age' => 'min:21', // Fail, but pass because of subset is all pass
    'time_at_job' => 'min:6' // Pass
    'monthly_income' => 'min:2000' // Pass
]

// If the original age fails and this passes, then age passes and continue to the original 
time_at_job.
[
    'age' => 'min:18, // Fail, but pass because of subset is all pass
    'time_at_job' => 'min:12' // Pass
    'monthly_income' => 'min:2500' // Pass
]

// If the subset age passed and this passes, then the subset age passes, but the subset 
time_at_job and monthly income will need to pass before the original age can pass.
[
    'age' => 'min:16, // Pass
    'time_at_job' => 'min:18' // Pass
    'monthly_income' => 'min:3000' // Pass
]
```

Any help on where to start with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine you could use a method call as the array value, like

```
public function rules(){
    return [
     'age' => $this->ageChildCheck(),
    ]
}
```

Then after the rules in the validator:

```
public function ageChildCheck(){
    $data = $this->validationData();
    if($data['time_at_job'] > passNumber && $data['monthly_income'] > passNumber2){
        return 'min:0';
    }else{
        return 'min:18';
    }
}
```

that should allow you to variably set what the validation rules will be in the end. Set it to 0 if it will auto pass if the conditions are met, and to 18 when they fail.